# missing return statement error and i don't know what's the error

Tags: java

Here is the code,

```
class Car
{
    public static String owner;
    public static String car;
    public static Integer plate_num;
    public static String car_color;

    Car(String owner, String car_name, Integer num, String color)
    {
        owner = owner;
        car = car_name;
        plate_num = num;
        car_color = color;
    }

    Void display ()
    {
        System.out.println("The owner of the car is  "+ owner + "and Car model is " + car);

        System.out.println("The  car number is  "+ plate_num + "and Car color is " + car_color);
    } // ---> here is the error

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Car car1 = new Car("MAriam", "Mini Cooper", 124834, "Navey");

        car1.display()  ;

        //System.out.println("Y3es");
    }
}
```

Comment: right time to start using IDE s . netbeans / eclipse

Answer (score 10):

Here you have a `Void` return. `Void` is actually a class.

To solve your problem you have to change it to `void` with lower case.

---

**Resources :**

- [javadoc - Void](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html)

Answer (score 2):

Colin's pointed out the most immediate problem, with the return type. However, your code has other problems too.

In particular, your variables are `static` - so if you created many `Car` instances and asked each of them to display themselves afterwards, they'd all show the name etc of the *last* constructor call.

You should not have the `static` modifier in the variable declarations. For the purposes of encapsulation, you should also make them private.

Also, this line is a no-op - and in a good IDE, it should be showing you a warning:

```
owner = owner;
```

That's just assigning the value of the parameter back to itself. When you've removed the `static` modifier from the fields, the statement can be changed to:

```
this.owner = owner;
```

Note that the only reason the other assignments don't have the same problem is that they're all using different names for the parameters to the fields... although inconsistently. (Sometimes the field is prefixed with `car_` and sometimes the parameter is.)

As Colin points out in the comments, using the default "package" access may not be what you want for the class, constructor and `display` method... but that's hard to say without more context.

Comment: There is more, such as the visibility of the classe/fields/methods (all to package? Really?) or the owner wich doesn't work in the constructor because of the `owner = owner`.

Comment: @Colin: It's hard to know whether the package visibility is actually a problem, but the assignment certainly is :) Will edit.

Comment: Excellent pointers. Jon, do you actually work besides answering questions on SO? (-; I'd like to add naming conventions to the list of gripes: car_color should be renamed carColor, or even better color (it is already a field of Car so doesn't need the prefix). See also http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html (the Sun err.. Oracle code conventions). Could it be that OP has a C background?

Comment: @Adriaan: Yes, I agree with those suggestions. I'd probably use `String` for the numberplate too, to cope with territories which don't just use numbers for plates. We could go on for a while :)